# How to remove errant diagnostic tint in build settings?

Tags: ios, xcode, build, interface-builder

I built an iOS app circa iOS 4.0+ and during the build process at some point I turned on highlights to diagnose the ad views for this app. Somehow the green diagnostic tint has never gone away and I've totally blanked on how to remove this effect. I do know that it seems to happen on my devices (across multiple restores of the app). I think there must be something in the build settings that is still active. Any thoughts on how I might make the ads (as seen in this sample) lose the green tint and just appear normally?

[image: green-tint]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't seen this problem posted elsewhere so here is the answer for others in this situation.

> **On your iOS device with this issue:**
>
> Navigate to:
>
> Settings > Developer > Highlight Clipped Banners
>
> Make sure the option is turned **OFF**